# Can the [maccatalyst] tag be remapped to [mac-catalyst]?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed the [maccatalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maccatalyst) tag but noticed this didn't use proper spacing.

Can a moderator please remap this to [mac-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-catalyst)?